# Replace with previous string in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have the following array in a JSON file, is there a way to replace each 'TODO' with the entry above it. For example, the first "TODO" should be "Previous question" and the second should be "Next question".

```
   [
      {          
        "englishDefault": "Previous question",
        "default": "TODO"
      },
      {
       "englishDefault": "Next question",
       "default": "TODO"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Hm.. Why do you need to get 2 entry with the same String ? + We need to know which language you use to process your json

Comment: When you say "the entry above it", will it always be the entry with the "englishDefault" key, or may it change?

Comment: @Aks, I'm using javascript.

Comment: @Aaron, it will always be "englishDefault".

Comment: As a side note, it's not a JSON array, it's just a JavaScript array ; JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is the serialized form of a JavaScript Object, where you represent it as a String. I assume you're not working on a String but rather on the native array

Comment: Hm, you are probably right. Although I left out the starting curly brackets for ease of reading.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/0DoqO check this code.

Comment: The curly brackets should be left there, they represent the start and end of an object. What you've posted is indeed the JSON representation of your objects (we wouldn't like you to post a memory dump and say "here, my objects are in there"), but you're however working with a JS array and JS objects rather than their JSON representation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it :

```
// with ES6
myArray.filter(i => i.default === "TODO").forEach(i => i.default = i.englishDefault);

//without ES6
for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    var cur = myArray[i];
    if (cur.default === "TODO") { cur.default = cur.englishDefault; }
}
```

Comment: It should only write over the `default` property if it is set to `"TODO"` tho

Comment: @Aaron, great answer. Is there a way to extend it to nested instances of "englishDefault"?

Comment: Yeah sure : you could test whether the current object's "englishDefault" field is defined ( !== undefined) and if it's not the case browse the object's field in search for an object with an "englishDefault" field

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how to browse the object. I created a different question that explains my problem better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086058/replace-nested-string-in-json

Answer (score 0):

Improving @Aaron answer, you can use a for each and a ternary operator.

```
for each (question in myArray) { question.default == "TODO" ? question.default = question.englishDefault : null; }
```